# Difference between もっとも and 一番

Tags: word-choice, usage, wago-and-kango

When expressing a superlative meaning ("the most ..."), what is the difference between the usage of もっとも and 一番？ (e.g. もっとも大きい vs. 一番大きい)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply, 一番 is colloquial/casual, and 最も is formal/technical. Oh, this is one of the rare cases where 漢語 words are more informal than the 和語 versions.

In addition, 最も can only function as a modifier, while 一番 can work as a noun which means *number one*.

> - 私が一番だ。: OK
> - 私が最もだ。: NG

Answer (score 0):

When expressing superlative, both もっとも and 一番 have the same meaning.

Here are the definitions of [もっとも](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219473/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82/) and [一番](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/12710/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93/) according to デジタル大辞泉.